# Issue with check in the file using SharePoint C# CSOM coding

Tags: csom

I need help with Sharepoint CSOM.
I have used this

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

```
//removed code
```

```
var context = new ClientContext(myURl);
var file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(FileUrl);
file.CheckOut();

var libraryFields = file.ListItemAllFields;

libraryFields["Title"] = "My title";
libraryFields.Update();

file.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

when I run the above code I get the following error:

The file "https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/myfile.tif" **is checked out for editing by i:0#.f|membership|myuser@domain.com**

Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong in my code.

Comment: You can try to do a `context.ExecuteQuery();` before `file.CheckIn` (but keep the last one as well) and see if that makes any difference

Comment: context.load(file) before you checout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the below code, before executing the context.ExecuteQuery() publish and load the file and also check for it is not checked out.

```
if (file.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None)
{
       file.CheckIn("Check in comment": "", checkInType: CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
            file.Publish(comment: "");

            context.Load(file);
            context.ExecuteQuery(); 
}
```